# hibernation at critical battery level not work

Tags: 14.04, power-management, hibernate

I use this tutorial ([hibernation enable](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/enable-hibernate-ubuntu-14-04/)) to put my Ubuntu 14.04 in hibernation.
All works well if I put my notebook in hibernation manually.
But I need at critical battery level it's put to hibernation automaticaly like windows do. I select this option in power manager, but notebook is simply turn off, without data saving. How I can fix this? 
Thank you.